# How can I dynamically name a template reference variable?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a lot of boilerplate code on my templates that follow roughly this structure.

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-6"
     [ngClass]="{'has-error': errors?.startDate || !startDate.valid}">
    <label>Start Date</label>
    <input class="form-control"
           [(ngModel)]="currentEntity.startDate"
           #startDate="ngModel" name="startDate"
           required />
    <small *ngIf="!startDate.valid" class="help-block">
        Start Date Is Required
    </small>
    <small *ngIf="errors?.startDate" class="help-block">
        {{errors.startDate}}
    </small>
</div>
```

The second error block is for any server validations that come back.

I was hoping to make a directive that could just be something like `<validatedInput [inputName] = "startDate" />` and replace the key elements in each property. Is there anyway to dynamically change things like `#startDate="ngModel"` to `#{{inputName}}="ngModel"`. ngIf would also have to be set up dynamically.

I'm running "@angular/forms": "0.1.1".

Comment: Have a look into the Angular 2 formbuilder. Using that I think you might be able to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Template variables are static-only. You can't name them dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template reference variables are static as Günter pointed out. However, using Angular 2 formbuilder you may not need them any longer.

In your component you can create the form group like this:
(Note: formbuilder needs to be injected into your component constructor.)

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group
({
    "startDate": [currentEntity.startDate, Validators.required],
    ...
});
```

and modify your html to something like this:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-6" [ngClass]="{'has-error': errors?.startDate || !startDate.valid}">
      <label>Start Date</label>
      <input class="form-control" [formControl]="myForm.controls['startDate']" name="startDate" />
      <small *ngIf="!myForm.controls['startDate'].valid" class="help-block">
       Start Date Is Required
       </small>
    ...
```

I am using the form syntax from RC4 here.
Furthermore, you might be able to iterate over the `FormGroup` array and create multiple such controls via an *ngFor.
(In order to do so you may need a temporary array into which to extract the relevant info from `FormGroup`).

Another advantage of `FormGroups` is the fact that their elements are `Observables` which allows you to do all kinds of interesting things.